# String Manipulation Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.6

I am trying to modify a string , by replacing each alphabet by an alphabet which is two postions ahead of it. e.g. 'a' replaced by 'c', 'b' replaced by 'd'. The only exceptions is 'y' should be replaced by 'a' and 'z' by 'b' (loops back to start).

I have written the following code for it, which seems to serve the purpose, but the output formatting kind of spoils it.

```
string = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb."
print string
for i in string:
    if i.isalpha():
        if ord(i)>120:
            print chr(ord(i)-24),
        else:
            print chr(ord(i)+2),
    else: 
        print i
```

**Output :**

```
g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb.
i   h o p e   y o u   d i d n t   t r a n s l a t e   i t   b y   h a n d .
```

**Expected Output:**

```
g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb.
i hope you didnt translate it by hand.
```

Is there any alternative, quicker approach to solve this?

Comment: `from string import translate` and use it.

Comment: thanks did the following as an alternate approach `intab = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
outtab= "cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab"
trantab = maketrans(intab, outtab)
print string.translate(trantab)`

Comment: cs50x? Really good course :)

Comment: This is called a [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) or shift cipher by the way. There are a bunch of questions on this on SO.

Comment: @korylprince thanks that was informative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `print i,` syntax adds a space at the end of the thing that's being printed. You could solve this by putting all your characters in a list and `''.join()`ing them in the end:

```
string = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb."
print string
answer = []
for i in string:
    if i.isalpha():
        if ord(i)>120:
            answer.append(chr(ord(i)-24))
        else:
            answer.append(chr(ord(i)+2))
    else: 
        answer.append(i)
print ''.join(answer)
```

Of course, as others have suggested, `string.translate` will likely be far more straightforward

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using string.translate:

```
from string import translate, maketrans, ascii_lowercase

s='g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb.'

rot2=maketrans(
    ascii_lowercase,
    ascii_lowercase[2:]+ascii_lowercase[:2]
    )

print s.translate(rot2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this horrific bastardization of a list comprehension.

```
message = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb."
print message
print ' '.join([''.join([chr(((ord(letter)+2) % 122) + int(ord(letter)/121.0)*96) if ord(letter)>96 else letter for letter in word]) for word in message.split()])
```